# Why int is not showing size in mysql when displaying with describe;

Tags: mysql

Create table t_t(sno int);
desc employees ;
It should display 
sno int(11);
but it is showing 
sno int
why?

Comment: This number means nothing. *As of MySQL 8.0.17, the display width attribute is deprecated for integer data types and support for it will be removed in a future MySQL version.* - [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Numeric Data Type Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html).

Comment: Does for me.Where are you running this describe from and what version of mysql are you on.